# What is the difference between sqrt(9) and sqrt(x=9) in R?

Tags: r

I have just started learning R and I am a little confused by the inputs to functions.

I see for example `sqrt(9)` and `sqrt(x=9)` being used interchangeably, and I don't understand why you would include the `x=`.

Comment: R functions can take arguments positionally or by name. The first argument's name is `x`. So, you can provide `x` as the first argument, or by `x = `. In this case, it doesn't matter much, but for other functions it can be useful for readability to name the arguments you are passing.

Comment: If you're new to R, I recommend that you name all your arguments. After a few years, you'll start to get lazy, like the rest of us, and omit the tedious argument naming business. Safety first. ;)

Comment: @duckmayr, post as answer?

Comment: @BenBolker I would, but surely this is a duplicate? I will try to find the (almost surely existing) duplicate

Comment: @BenBolker Guess I was wrong! (Or at least it's not an easy to find duplicate). Will add as answer

Comment: See [R Language Definition 4.3.2 Argument matching](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Argument-matching)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When passing arguments to a function in R, you can do it one of two ways:

1. By position
2. By name

In the case of `sqrt()`, it would never matter; there's only one argument, `x`. So, let's think about a function with multiple arguments where this could potentially matter:

```r
foo <- function(a, b) a^b
a <- 2
b <- 3
foo(a, b)
# [1] 8
foo(b, a)
# [1] 9
foo(b = b, a = a)
# [1] 8
```

This illustrates *one* reason why you might want to name your arguments instead of just passing by position; it *ensures* that you're always giving the values to each argument that you *think* you are. Another reason to name arguments is for readability for those reading you're code who may not know what the arguments of a function you're using are.

For those reasons, some would say it's good practice to name your arguments even perhaps in a situation (like maybe `sqrt()`) where it might seem unnecessary. Although I generally err on the side of passing arguments to functions by name rather than position, IMO it's a little overkill for something like `sqrt()`.